# Show a module is simple

Tags: abstract-algebra

Let $M$ be a non-zero module and suppose that every non-zero module homomorphism $f:M\rightarrow N$ is injective. Show that $M$ is simple.

My idea is to let $N$ be a submodule; then pick a map to show it must be zero or $M$.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are on the right track. Choose $N$ to be a submodule, and take $f:M \rightarrow M/N$ to be the quotient map. Can you proceed now?

Comment: Ker(f)=N but f is not injective so how do we proceed?

Comment: So this contradicts the hypothesis-right?

Comment: Hence no submodules, so M simple.

Comment: oh  I got confused; M/N is just another 'N'. Taking N to be a proper submodule the quotient map has kernel N={0} by injectivity. Thanks